# Cannot get value form TextField in materia-ui

Tags: forms, reactjs, submit, textfield, material-ui

Parent Component

```
export default class Parent extends Component {
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('1', e.target);
    // the result is like <form><div>...<input/></div></form>
    console.log('2', e.target.value);
    // the result is undefined
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          {this.state.products.map((val) => (val))}
          <RaisedButton type="submit" label="Submit" primary={true}/>
          <RaisedButton label="Add" primary={true} onClick={this.handleAdd}/>
        </form>
      </div>

    )
  }
}
```

Child Component

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <TextField
        id="name"
        placeholder="Name"
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
      <TextField
        id="brand"
        placeholder="Brand"
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

The `this.state.products.map((val) => (val))` in Parent Component is to add Child component. When click the ADD button, state is changed(increase) and then child component is added. Plus, I add `this.handleChange` in Child component, and the result of `e.target.value` is correct.

Even I can get `e.target.value` from `this.handleChange` in Child component, why can't I get `e.target.value` from `this.handleSubmit` in Parent component?

Answer (score 0):

It's to be expected, `<form>` on it's own doesn't have `value` property. It's children, on the other hand - do have `value` property populated (if they are form elements), so your `<TextField>` (which - I assume - is an `<input>`) logs your inputted data and form does not.

You can check the comprehensive API for `form` element at the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement), valid properties would be:

- elements
- length
- name
- method
- target
- action
- encoding/enctype
- acceptCharset
- autocomplete
- noValidate